# Converting pandas.DataFrame to bytes

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, type-conversion, dataframe

I need convert the data stored in a `pandas.DataFrame` into a byte string where each column can have a separate data type (integer or floating point).  Here is a simple set of data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([ 10, 15, 20], dtype='u1', columns=['a'])
df['b'] = np.array([np.iinfo('u8').max, 230498234019, 32094812309], dtype='u8')
df['c'] = np.array([1.324e10, 3.14159, 234.1341], dtype='f8')
```

and df looks something like this:

```
    a            b                  c
0   10  18446744073709551615    1.324000e+10
1   15  230498234019            3.141590e+00
2   20  32094812309             2.341341e+02
```

The `DataFrame` knows about the types of each column `df.dtypes` so I'd like to do something like this:

```
data_to_pack = [tuple(record) for _, record in df.iterrows()]
data_array = np.array(data_to_pack, dtype=zip(df.columns, df.dtypes))
data_bytes = data_array.tostring()
```

This typically works fine but in this case (due to the maximum value stored in `df['b'][0]`.  The second line above converting the array of tuples to an `np.array` with a given set of types causes the following error:

```
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

The error results (I believe) in the first line which extracts the record as a `Series` with a single data type (defaults to `float64`)  and the representation chosen in `float64` for the maximum `uint64` value is not directly convertible back to `uint64`.

1) Since the `DataFrame` already knows the types of each column is there a way to get around creating a row of tuples for input into the typed `numpy.array` constructor?  Or is there a better way than outlined above to preserve the type information in such a conversion?

2) Is there a way to go directly from `DataFrame` to a byte string representing the data using the type information for each column.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`df.to_records()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_records.html) to convert your dataframe to a numpy recarray, then call `.tostring()` to convert this to a string of bytes:

```
rec = df.to_records(index=False)

print(repr(rec))
# rec.array([(10, 18446744073709551615, 13240000000.0), (15, 230498234019, 3.14159),
#  (20, 32094812309, 234.1341)], 
#           dtype=[('a', '|u1'), ('b', '<u8'), ('c', '<f8')])

s = rec.tostring()
rec2 = np.fromstring(s, rec.dtype)

print(np.all(rec2 == rec))
# True
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([ 10, 15, 20], dtype='u1', columns=['a'])
df_byte = df.to_json().encode()
print(df_byte)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.