# How to convert a pandas dataframe to a bytes string?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe, types

I have a pandas dataframe as following named as df

[image]

I want to convert this dataframe to a bytes string which is having type **bytes** i.e when I enter `type(df)` it should give me an output of `Bytes` instead of `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` The output should look like following:

```
b'Age,Height,Weight,City\r\n23,5.45,67,New York\r\n'
```

Comment: df is constructed with pandas.DataFrame(). Thus, it is a pandas.core.frame.DataFrame. could you provide a minimum working example of your input data also? you'd need to transform the columns of the dataframe/concatenate it somehow to produce output of your definition.

Comment: if you take this dataframe as a csv and read it using data = open('df.csv', 'rb').read() it gives you data in b'Age,Height,Weight,City\r\n23,5.45,67,New York\r\n' form which is what I want directly from dataframe instead of csv.

Comment: so you could write the dataframe into a temp.csv 'df.to_csv("temp.csv")' and then read it as you presented? also there seems to be something similar in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34666860/converting-pandas-dataframe-to-bytes

Comment: that is not a solution

Comment: I know, I'm just trying to clarify the problem, because you did not provide a working example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can convert your dataframe to csv string, then to bytes:

```
bytes(df.to_csv(line_terminator='\r\n', index=False), encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Your answer is almost 99% right, however the output i am getting from your code is also throwing ',' in the start which is not what i expect. the output from your code is  -----> 
     b',Age,Height,Weight,City\r\n23,5.45,67,New York\r\n'

Comment: I want output as -----> b'Age,Height,Weight,City\r\n23,5.45,67,New York\r\n'

Comment: @NikhilMangire pass `index=False` into `to_csv`. See update.