# how to send a pandas dataframe to azure service bus

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, azureservicebus

I have a Postgres database. for example, I wanna read 10 last row data on a table and send it to the Azure service bus.
In the below code I read a sample table and save it. After that I wanna sent to the Azure service bus, I receive:

> TypeError: ServiceBusMessage body must be a string, bytes, or None.  Got instead: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

What is the solution to send table data to the Azure service bus?
My code is:

```
import os
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient, ServiceBusMessage


conndb = psycopg2.connect(
    database="testDB", user="postgres", password="****", host="127.0.0.1", port="5432"
)
connstr = "Endpoint=****"
queue_name = '****'


data = pd.read_sql_query('select * from cricketers', conndb)
# print(data)

with ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(connstr) as client:
    with client.get_queue_sender(queue_name) as sender:
        single_message = ServiceBusMessage(data)
        sender.send_messages(single_message)
```

Comment: May be convert your DataFrame to bytes before sending. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34666860/converting-pandas-dataframe-to-bytes

Comment: @AhmadAnis Thanks, I convert to string with `dataframe.to_string()`, and the problem solved

Comment: @Shadi Glad to know you have it working now. Please post what worked for you as an answer below so it helps others in the community as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just post an answer to end this question:

> I convert to string with dataframe.to_string(), and the problem solved